# Help solving probability problem!

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Can you help solve this problem?

Place contains $N$ coupons $(N>3)$. $3$ tickets have prizes $ \$10000, \$1000, \$500$ respectively. $X$ is the number of coupons drawn before a prize-containing coupon is chosen.

How do I find $E[X]$? If $Y$ is the number of coupons left in the place when all $3$ prize-containing coupons were drawn. What's $E[Y]$? What's $\mathrm{Var}(X-Y)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Label the non-winning tickets $1$, $2$, and so on up to $N-3$. let $X_i=1$ non-winning ticket $i$ is drawn **before** any winning ticket is drawn. Let $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Let
$$X=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{N-3}.$$ 
The sum of the $X_i$ is the number of tickets drawn **before** a winner is drawn. We really mean **before**. So if you want to include the draw in which the first winning ticket is obtained, the random variable you are interested in is $X+1$. But of course if we find $E(X)$, we just add $1$ to find $E(X+1)$.

The $X_i$ are **not** independent. However, expectation *always* has the following linearity property:
$$E(X)=E(X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots +E(X_n).$$

Now we find $\Pr(X_i=1)=E(X_i)$. This is the probability that non-winning ticket $i$ is drawn before any winner. All orders of the tickets are equally likely. The probability ticket $i$ comes before any winner is therefore $\dfrac{1}{4}$

Now we are finished! We have
$$E(X)=\frac{N-3}{4}.$$

If you want to count also the draw on which we got the first winner, add $1$.

A nearly identical  argument will take care of $E(Y)$. We can define random variable $Y_i$ to be $1$ if all the winners are before non-winner $i$, and $0$ otherwise. Or more simply, film the drawing and play the movie in reverse!

I have not thought about the variance problem.

**Added** The variance is not too bad. Note that $E(X-Y)=0$, so we want $E((X-Y)^2)$.   Express $X$ and $Y$ in terms of the $X_i$ and $Y_i$, and expand. We have $X_i^2=X_i$ and $Y_i^2=Y_i$. But there is a mess of cross terms to deal with. We will need the probability that $X_i=1$ **and** $X_j=1$ ($i\ne j$), and also the probability that $X_i=1$ **and** $Y_j=1$ (all pairs $(i,j)$). These are all accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  what is the probability that the first coupon is not a winner?  what is the probability that the first ten coupons are not winners?  Can you use this to find $E[X]$?

Can you find an easy relation between $N, E[X], E[Y]$ that will save the work of calculating $E[Y]$?

Comment: Hum... E[X] = (N-i)-3/N-10? I don't get the easy relation you talked about...

Comment: @user1172558:  $E[X]$ can't depend on $i$, only on $N$ and constants.  There is no $i$ in the problem.  For the easy relation, think about drawing the tickets in the reverse order.

Comment: Do you recommend any readings to help me? Maybe a book? I need to solve this problem, but I can't find a way to think about it.